# Is it okay to name a section in a document "Body Text"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

I have a large guideline document. It starts with some preliminary sections describing the guideline's scope and its legislative and regulatory underpinnings. Then goes the section titled (literally) in Russian "The Main Text of the Document". It contains the guideline proper, that is, the requirements and the rules and so on.

Is it okay to name it "[Body Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_text)" in English? Or is this term used only by typesetters and designers?

What could be other acceptable titles? "Main Section"?

Multitran offers [these translations for Russian "основной текст"](http://www.multitran.ru/c/M.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%EE%F1%ED%EE%E2%ED%EE%E9%20%F2%E5%EA%F1%F2%20) but I guess "Main Section" might be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "body text" can be used if you mean to map a *style* to that kind of section, but it is not common to make that the actual *title* of any section of a document.  I do know that in formal research papers each section will be named, depending on the common practices of that subject matter, but otherwise the "body" of the document does not need to have any special title.